# Why is the data in the service not updated from the directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

With the following setup I try to update data that is being held in a service and shared with the controller to assign it to the view.

In the example you can see 2 variables. One containing an array, another just a string.

What I don't understand is **why is the array updated and consumed in the view and the string is not**?!

JavaScript:

```
function fooService() {
    var mystring = 'old string';
    var myarray = [];

    var updateArray = function(data) {
        myarray.push(data);
    };

    var updateString = function(data) {
        mystring = data;
    };

    return {
      myarray: myarray,
      mystring: mystring,
      updateString: updateString,
      updateArray: updateArray
    }
}

function MainCtrl($scope, fooService) {
    this.myarray = fooService.myarray;
    this.mystring = fooService.mystring;
}

function fooDirective(fooService) {

    function link(scope) {

      fooService.updateArray(scope.vm.name);
      fooService.updateString('new string');

    }

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        template: '<h2 style="color: {{vm.color}};">{{vm.name}}</h2>',
        scope: {},
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: {
            name: '@',
            color: '@'
        },
        link: link
    };
}

angular
    .module('app', [])
    .service('fooService', fooService)
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
    .directive('fooDirective', fooDirective);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
        {{vm.myarray}}
        {{vm.mystring}}
        <foo-directive data-name="Markus" data-color="red"></foo-directive>
        <foo-directive data-name="Nemanja" data-color="green"></foo-directive>
        <foo-directive data-name="Luke" data-color="blue"></foo-directive>
    </div>
</div>
```

It might just be that I understand it the wrong way but services should hold data that is shared across the app right?

Here is the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/markus_falk/f00y3tL3/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> services should hold data that is shared across the app right?

This is correct, however when you do

```
return {
  myarray: myarray,
  mystring: mystring,
  // ...
}
```

you return new object (that will be your service instance) that has **reference** to `myarray` and **copy** of `mystring`. So since there is reference to `myarray` (all objects are passed as a reference) it updates in the service just fine. However, it will not for with the string (primitive types are not-mutable, passed as values), because service returns just a copy of it.

Instead of modifying a string (primitive value) use getter/setter approach.

Comment: Aha! I was caught in thinking it had to do with the digest cycle or something similar. So this also applies to objects then?: http://jsfiddle.net/markus_falk/f00y3tL3/6/

Comment: No, it's more tricky. When you do `myarray.push(data);` you **modify** myarray`, so it is reflected in the view too. It's clear. However, with `myobject = data;` it will not work because you **overwrite** object reference completely with the new reference. So you break reference, and it will no longer points to original one and won't update.

Comment: You could for example modify the **same** object without breaking reference: `var updateObject = function(data) { angular.extend(myobject, data); };` here you modify existing `myobject` without creating new object and removing old reference.

Comment: However you can't modify the string "in place" because primitive string value is not mutable, which means that you can't modify it without creating new string. So the only thing to do with `mystring` is to use `updateString` and `getString = function() { return mystring; }` methods.

Comment: Here is the example of how you can always modify existing object (which is the service object itself) without worrying about references. http://jsfiddle.net/dLLuqs0g/